# Convert Pandas TimeDelta to integer

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a Pandas Series that contains TimeDelta data.
In fact it has been generated by taking the difference of a DateTimeIndex with a shifted version of itself, hence giving the delta between consecutive timestamps.

It looks something like

```
timestamp
2015-02-01 00:00:04   00:00:04
2015-02-01 00:00:08   00:00:04
2015-02-01 00:00:12   00:00:04
....
Name: ﻿timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The values are obviously numpy.timedelta64 but I need to get them into seconds.
There have been similar questions asked relating to this but no answers I have seen yet that deals with Pandas 0.16.1.

What I've tried is:

```
ts.apply(lambda x: x.seconds)
```

Which gives an error of

> AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'seconds'

Then tried

```
numpy.int64(ts)
```

But that gives me an array. Now I know I can convert that back into a Series but is there not another way to do this in one Pandas call or mapping function?

Comment: Are you running version 0.15.0 or higher? if so shouldn't `ts.dt.second` work?

Comment: Why yes. So it does. (Running 0.16.1 and am going to look this up in the docs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
In [24]:

t="""index,timestamp
2015-02-01 00:00:04,00:00:04
2015-02-01 00:00:08,00:00:04
2015-02-01 00:00:12,00:00:04"""
s = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),parse_dates=[0,1], squeeze=True, index_col=[0])
In [26]:

s.dt.second
Out[26]:
index
2015-02-01 00:00:04    4
2015-02-01 00:00:08    4
2015-02-01 00:00:12    4
dtype: int64
```

datetime dtype values have a [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) accessor where you can access the seconds attribute.

Comment: What if the timedelta is in the index?

Comment: @Sören you should be able to just to `df.index.seconds` so no need for `.dt`